# Crear tabla HTML con Javascript

Tags: javascript

He creado un array bidimensional en el cual se van añadiendo productos. Bien, pretendo crear otra funcion para poder recorrer dicho array e ir insertando los datos en una tabla HTML. Pero no se como seguir...

```
   function añadirProducto(){
            productos = new Array();
            elementos = parseInt(prompt("¿ Cuantos productos quieres añadir ?"));
            for (var i = 0; i < elementos; i++) {
                id_producto = prompt("Introduce el id del producto: ");
                producto = prompt("Introduce el nombre de producto: ");
                cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Introduce la cantidad: "));
                precio = parseFloat(prompt("Introduce el precio: "));

                productos.push(new Array(id_producto,producto,cantidad,precio));
            }

            return productos;
        }

function generar_tabla(){
            productos = añadirProducto();

            for (var i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < productos[i].length; j++) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Ya no se como seguir en la funcion generar tabla para obtener la tabla en HTML...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para generar el HTML lo más fácil es crearte una variable e ir asignando el `HTML` como `string`.

Te dejo aquí el ejemplo (no lo he metido en una función pero sería fácil hacerlo). He cambiado también para que en vez de trabajar con un `array` dentro de otro trabajes con un `array` de objetos.

```js
function añadirProducto(){
            productos = new Array();
            elementos = parseInt(prompt("¿ Cuantos productos quieres añadir ?"));
            for (let i = 0; i < elementos; i++) {
                id_producto = prompt("Introduce el id del producto: ");
                producto = prompt("Introduce el nombre de producto: ");
                cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Introduce la cantidad: "));
                precio = parseFloat(prompt("Introduce el precio: "));

                productos.push({id: id_producto, prod:producto, cant:cantidad, pr:precio});
            }

            return productos;
        }

function generar_tabla(){
     productos = añadirProducto();

    let myTable= "<table><tr><td style='width: 100px; color: red;'>ID</td>";
    myTable+= "<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Nombre</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Cantidad</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; color: red; text-align: right;'>Precio</td></tr>";
    myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;'>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td>";
    myTable+="<td style='width: 100px; text-align: right;'>---------------</td></tr>";    

    for (let i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
          myTable+="<tr><td style='width: 100px;text-align: right;'>" + productos[i].id + "</td>";        
          myTable+="<td style='width: 100px;text-align: right;'>" + productos[i].prod + "</td>";    
          myTable+="<td style='width: 100px;text-align: right;'>" + productos[i].cant + "</td>";    
          myTable+="<td style='width: 100px;text-align: right;'>" + productos[i].pr + "</td>";    
          myTable+="</tr>";
    }
      
      myTable+="</table>";
      document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
  }
  
  generar_tabla();
```

```html
<div id="tablePrint"> </div>
```

**Edito**: Añado una solución con `string templates`:

```js
function añadirProducto(){
            productos = new Array();
            elementos = parseInt(prompt("¿ Cuantos productos quieres añadir ?"));
            for (let i = 0; i < elementos; i++) {
                id_producto = prompt("Introduce el id del producto: ");
                producto = prompt("Introduce el nombre de producto: ");
                cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Introduce la cantidad: "));
                precio = parseFloat(prompt("Introduce el precio: "));

                productos.push(new Array(id_producto, producto, cantidad, precio));
            }
            return productos;
        }


function getCells(data, type) {
  return data.map(cell => `<${type}>${cell}</${type}>`).join('');
}

function createBody(data) {
  return data.map(row => `<tr>${getCells(row, 'td')}</tr>`).join('');
}

function createTable(data) {
  let cabeceras = ['ID', 'Nombre', 'Cantidad', 'Precio'];
  return `
    <table>
      <thead>${getCells(cabeceras, 'th')}</thead>
      <tbody>${createBody(data)}</tbody>
    </table>
  `;
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', createTable(añadirProducto()));
```

Comment: Ya no es necesario concatenar. Usando [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) es la forma más limpia.

Comment: Cierto, añado ejemplo con string templates.